# SQL server - advanced grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have at table containing procurement contracts that looks like this:

```
+------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| type | text      | date       | company | supplierID | name      |
+ -----+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 0    | None      | 2004-03-29 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 0    | None      | 2007-09-30 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 0    | None      | 2010-11-29 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 2    | Strategic | 2011-01-01 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 0    | None      | 2012-04-10 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
+------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

In this example the first three rows the contract is the same. So I only want the first one.
The row with type = 2 is a change in procurement contract with the given supplier. I want to select that row as well.
On the last row the contract changes back to 0, so I want to select that row as well.

Basically I want to select the first row and the rows where the contract type changes. So the result should look like this:

```
+------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| type | text      | date       | company | supplierID | name      |
+ -----+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 0    | None      | 2004-03-29 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 2    | Strategic | 2011-01-01 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
| 0    | None      | 2012-04-10 | 310     | 227234     | HRC INFRA |
+------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Any suggestions to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS Id,
         type, text, date, company, supplierId, name
  FROM your_table
  )
  SELECT c1.type, c1.text, c1.date, c1.company,
         c1.supplierId, c1.name
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.id = c2.id + 1
  WHERE c2.text IS NULL OR c1.text != c2.text
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4506f/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SQL server in front of me to test it out so I'm not going to attempt the actual solution for it right now, but fyi there are few things you need:

1) A way to make sure the records are ordered properly.  I don't see any kind of an id here which means you have no guarantee that they will appear in that order.  I assume there is one so just make sure you order by it

2) You need to do an outer join on the table to itself on whatever the index is, but instead of "table1.index = table2.index" it will look like "table1.index = table2.index + 1".  If your indexes aren't sequential then it will make joining them this way more complex than that though.

3) In the where clause you'll specify something like

```
where table1.type <> table2.type
```

That will get you most the way there.  That won't pick up the very first record though since there is no record before the first record to compare to so you'll need an OR addition to compensate for that.  And I'm assuming that type has no NULL values.

Sorry I couldn't be more help with an actual implementation but maybe someone else will take care of that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

might be what you want. Presumingly you dont have type < 0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE] as ot where ot.type <> 
(select top 1 coalesce(it.type, -1) from [TABLE] as it where it.date < ot.date order by it.date desc)
```

Also, take not of brandon note to make shure tables are ordered, due i dont see PK.

Comment: Nice query. Just `UNION` your result with `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Table]` and you get the result this question asked for. Order by date in the outermost select is a nice addition too.

Comment: yea, you are right. I'm not having tool with me atm, and cba to go to sqlfiddle to build table. +1 for pointing a flaw. thx.